# Multi Datepicker in Django

Tags: python, django, jquery-multidatespicker

I'm quite new in Django. I can embed datepicker(single) to my website. However, I don't know how can I use multiple datepicker. I want to use multiple datepicker with database(as a list or something like that). How can I do this?

Comment: How do you include a single one? Why do you think you can not *repeat* that to include a second one?

Comment: Single datepicker means that user can select just one date but in my website user must select more than three date at the same time from one datepicker.